# How to export query to file

Tags: sql, apache-drill

I need export a query to a file. I'm trying with

```
(SELECT A.*
FROM dfs.ff.`filea.json` A
  LEFT JOIN dfs.ff.`fileb.json` B ON (A.quote = B.quote)
WHERE B.C IS NULL) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION dfs.ff.`result.csv`;
```

But throws me a error

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "don't works"?

Answer (score 0):

Use BCP utility

```
bcp "SELECT A.*
FROM dfs.ff.`filea.json` A
  LEFT JOIN dfs.ff.`fileb.json` B ON (A.quote = B.quote)
WHERE B.C IS NULL" queryout "D:\MyTable.csv" -c -t , -S SERVERNAME -T
```

The -c argument specifies character output, as opposed to SQL's native binary format; this defaults to tab-separated values, but -t , changes the field terminator to commas.  -T specifies Windows authentication ("trusted connection"), otherwise use -U MyUserName -P MyPassword.

This doesn't export column headers by default. You need to use a UNION ALL for headers

OR

```
Use SQLCMD



 SQLCMD -S SERVERNAME -E -Q "SELECT A.*
    FROM dfs.ff.`filea.json` A
      LEFT JOIN dfs.ff.`fileb.json` B ON (A.quote = B.quote)
    WHERE B.C IS NULL"
        -s "," -o "D:\MyData.csv"
```

Also

http://www.egenconsulting.com/output-sql-to-csv/

http://solvedstack.com/questions/is-there-a-select-into-outfile-equivalent-in-sql-server-management-studio

Comment: I'm using apache drill on linux, I think those utilities are for Windows

Comment: I recently start to using apache drill I'm using the console when execute the bin/drill-embedded

Answer (score 0):

Use the Drill shell command !record to record all output to a specified file. http://drill.apache.org/docs/configuring-the-drill-shell/

Answer (score 0):

Use CTAS for the purpose. Don't forget to define `store.format` (default is parquet). Doc ref: https://drill.apache.org/docs/create-table-as-ctas/.